# sorting lists with Locale

Tags: android, sorting

I would like to sort an `ArrayList<Object>`. ( alphabet sort)

I am using below codes to sorting :

```
    Collections.sort(arr_items, new Comparator<Helper>() {


        @Override
        public int compare(Helper one, Helper two) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return one.getTitle().compareTo(two.getTitle());
        }

    });
```

now if I want to set a `Locale` to it how can I do ?

```
    Locale arrabic= new Locale("ar");
    Collator arrabicCollator = Collator.getInstance(arrabic);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Comparator` needs to use the `Collator` like this:

```
Locale arrabic= new Locale("ar");
final Collator arrabicCollator = Collator.getInstance(arrabic);
Collections.sort(arr_items, new Comparator<Helper>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Helper one, Helper two) {
        return arrabicCollator.compare(one.getTitle(), two.getTitle());
    }

});
```

for the sorting.

Comment: I've added more detail for you